# Branches to Build Configurations?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a single build pipeline that builds on develop, and master branches. I have multiple build configurations set up. Once develop builds, a release is created and it is deployed to my development environment. I want this build to use my development build configuration. When I merge into my master branch, it builds, releases, and deploys to my QA environment. I want this build to use my release build configuration. The problem I'm having, it seems to build all build configurations, but the last one sticks and that's the release build configuration. This is problematic when deploying to development as my connection strings are pointing to my production databases. Is there a way to properly set this up using a single CI/CD pipeline or should I have two different CI/CD pipelines, one for develop and one for production?

Answer (score 2):

This is something I needed too, and I solved it.

For the BUILD:

1. Make sure your build trigger is set to allow 'filter' any branches
   that you want included in this. For me, it is develop and master.
2. Create a PowerShell build step, mine is called 'Set Build Config Based on Branch'.
3. Make the PowerShell an 'inline' type
4. In the script box, place the following:

   ```
   Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildConfiguration;]{0}" -f ({Test},{Release})[$env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME -eq "master"])
   ```

   *As long as your transforms are set to act on the build config, they will get    handled correctly in the rest of this build process. For me, it is a Test and Release config, but for you, it could be different.*

For the RELEASE:

1. Set the trigger on your artifacts to include the branches that you
   want included in this scenario.
2. Make sure you create separate stages in release. For me, they are
   called 'test deployment' and 'prod deployment'
3. For each of these deployment 'stages', set the trigger to have an
   artifact filer of the branch you are targeting.

CAUTION: Make sure that the deployment step in each 'stage' is targeting the appropriate Deployment group. You don't want to deploy test environment settings out to PROD!

For my prod stage, I also add a step for approval.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use **one** (or two) **build pipeline and two release pipeline**, since you want to use different release configurations based on the build branch is `develop` or `master`.

Detail as below:

- Still use current CI build pipeline for `develop` branch or `master` branch (or you can change to use two separate build pipelines).
- Use two release pipeline line. For the artifact specification, select Latest from a specific branch with tags. Then select `develop` or `master` for the two release pipelines separately.

  [image]

Comment: I added the tags in the pipeline and that seemed to have solve my issue. Of course, I figured it out after I ask the question. I was able to use a single pipeline and when "develop" builds, I simply added "development" to the tag and "release" on my "master" branch and it works well.

Comment: @Humpy Since your problem has been solved, you can add another answer for the solution you finally use, and mark the answer. It will also benefit others who have similar questions.